# ReactJS Pagination Help Buttons not properly working

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a table app component that takes data from an API (https://retoolapi.dev/HKpCV2/data) with 25 items of data split up into 3 pages (a 10 item limit each page). While the data for the first page is rendering correctly, I am unable to navigate to the other pages with the functions I created for the buttons first, previous, next, and last. None of the buttons work and I am unable to fix this issue. Below shows a detailed breakdown of each section in the code:

**this.state & componentDidMount to Fetch API**

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      err: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      users: [],
      curr_page: 1,
      per_page: null,
      total: 0
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const { curr_page } = this.state;
    fetch(`https://retoolapi.dev/HKpCV2/data?_page=${curr_page}`)
      .then(
        (res) => {
        if(res.ok) {
          if(res.status >= 400){
            throw new Error("Server responds with error!")
          }
          return res.json();
        }
      })
      .then(
        (data) => {
          this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            users: data,
            isLoaded: true
          });
        },
        (err) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            err
          });
        }
      );
  }
```

**Button Functions**

```
  goToFirstPage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      curr_page: 1
    })
  }

  goToPrevPage = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      curr_page: this.state.curr_page - 1
    })
  }

  goToNextPage = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      curr_page: this.state.curr_page - 1
    })   
  }

  goToLastPage = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      curr_page: null //replace with total number of pages
    }) 
  }
```

**Main.js**

```
render(){
    const { users, isLoaded } = this.state;

    const renderData = users.map((user) => {
      return(
        <tbody key={user.id}>
          <td>{user.id}</td>
          <td>{user.firstName}</td>
          <td>{user.lastName}</td>
        </tbody>
      )
    })

    if(!isLoaded){
      return(
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th>S/N</th>
            <th>FN</th>
            <th>LN</th>
          </thead>
          {renderData}
        </table>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.goToFirstPage}>&lt;&lt;</button>
          <button onClick={this.goToPrevPage}>&lt;</button>
          <button onClick={this.goToNextPage}>&gt;</button>
          <button onCLick={this.goToLastPage}>&gt;&gt;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only fetching on `componentDidMount`. You need to fetch any time the state changes, which can be detected with the `componentDidUpdate` method.

To keep the code DRY, since `componentDidUpdate` isn't called for the initial render, abstract the network request into a separate function that can be called both in that and in `componentDidMount`.

```
getData = () => {
  const { curr_page } = this.state;
  fetch(`https://retoolapi.dev/HKpCV2/data?_page=${curr_page}`)
    // etc
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.getData();
}
componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
  if (prevState.curr_page !== this.state.curr_page) {
    this.setState({
      isLoaded: false
    });
    this.getData();
  }
}
```

As you've noticed already, you should also change

```
  goToNextPage = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      curr_page: this.state.curr_page - 1
```

to

```
  goToNextPage = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      curr_page: this.state.curr_page + 1
```

Comment: [`this.setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) does a shallow merge by default, so spreading isn't necessary.

Comment: I have input this into my code, but the pages are still not changing as I click the buttons

Comment: @NewCSDeveloper Any console errors? Do you see a request going out when the button is pressed? You can add `console.log`s to see which lines of code are running - check that the button handler, and then the `componentDidUpdate`, and then the `getData` is running.

Comment: Ah I see! I resolved my error with goToNextPage and saw that the state of curr_page was decreasing when it should be increasing. Do you know how I would be able to access the last page (goToLastPage) without adding the last page number to ```this.state.curr_page```

Comment: @NewCSDeveloper Just from the code here, I don't see where the last page could be determined from the API - you'll probably need to examine its documentation to see if the final page is included in the API response, or on another endpoint